# source only allowed values in JQuery UI autocomplete plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is is possible to restrict the user input to only the source values with [JQuery autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete)?

For example, if the source array contains `"Bold","Normal","Default","100","200"`, the user is allowed to only type those values.

Comment: sorry for the "weird" question, but why not make a select box instead ?

Comment: I want a nice look and feel. I think this is appealing

Comment: well, think of a great looking car, that you have to drive in reverse....
would you buy it ? i dont think so, since you will be annoyed by driving backwards....

Comment: @Rephael Herjcovici I believe we don't agree in this. It's ok, we don't have to. I just asked if it was possible. I value your advice.

Comment: np, but i am sure a lot of people will agree that it is the wrong way to do what you want.
hint: did you know that if you focus on a select box, and start typing a value, it will select the value?

Comment: @tou have you considered what happen if user disables javascript?

Comment: @Rephael Herjcovici in a Select tag, it only works for the first letter. It only helps you filter by the first letter, at least in IE. With this, He can choose. He can either type or select it. BTW, your car analogy would be manual vs automatic, not reverse shift. A lot of people prefer manual.

Comment: @Mauro This is an internal app. Javascript must be enabled, as well as they have to use IE 7. Soon to be 8.

Comment: Well you cannot know if someone disables javascript and if you rely on user for data input, I would seriously review your server-side code to take into account unexpected data ;) Finally, autocomplete should have the list of possible entries in an array form, just write your own method that check if textbox text is present in the array on focus change or on form submission. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mauro I agree with you. Just as you never know who might be using Firebug to change the values that are gonna be posted.

Comment: @tou - you can type the whole thing into a select ( it just have to be really fast ), not just the first letter. and the car analogy was not Manual vs Automatic... since you are trying to change the standarts ( select/list for pre-defined values) and putting up an autocomplete, which you are trying to force limit.... So basicly, you are trying to change the way people are used to work on web apps/sites.
putting an autocomplete textbox with predefined values, might annoy and frustrate your users, which are your CLIENTS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you already have a solution.  Here's a similar way to do this, since I already put some time in on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/j3AN7/

```
var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200"]
previousValue = "";

$('#ac').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: validOptions
}).keyup(function() {
    var isValid = false;
    for (i in validOptions) {
        if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
            isValid = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isValid) {
        this.value = previousValue
    } else {
        previousValue = this.value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I like your solution better because it works on every keystroke. It gives feedback to the user quicker.

Comment: what happens if the input simply looses focus (e.g. by left clicking outside of the input), then the value wont be corrected. So, it also needs `onblur` handler which will correct value.

Comment: add `break;` after `isValid = true;` in for loop. Once is set to true, there's no need to iterate further

Answer (score 4):

I have a simple alternative. Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/uwR3Z/2/

Basically an onChange event on the textbox to clear out the value works the same.

Here is the js:

```
var validOptions = ["Bold", "Normal", "Default", "100", "200"];

$('#auto-complete-input').autocomplete({
    autoFocus: true,
    source: validOptions
});

function clearAutoCompleteInput() {
    $("#auto-complete-input").val('');
}
```

And html:

```
<label for="auto-complete-input">Select one: </label>
<input id="auto-complete-input" type="text" onChange="clearAutoCompleteInput()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment made by Rephael, as you want to limit the possible values to the one in autocomplete, a safer choice would be to have a select dropdown.
As a final user can be frustrating to enter data in a textbox and not being able to write what I want. The choice of a select dropdown is "socially" accepted to be limited.

Comment: Answer to be completed with comments on question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way.

Add the following option to the plugin. This works for when the source is an array.

```
change: function (event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex($(this).val()) + "$", "i"),
                                    valid = false;

        $.each(YOUR_SOURCE_ARRAY_NAME, function (index, value) {
               if (value.match(matcher)) {
               this.selected = valid = true;
                   return false;
               }
            });
            if (!valid) {
                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                $(this).val("");
            return false;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I what I do is

1. set a flag to false when entering the field (onfocus)
2. Set the flag to true in the autocomplete select event
3. Test that flag in the field onblur event.

If it is true the input is good, otherwise it is bad.